# Grails 2.x Multiple Projects in one Site

Tags: grails, war, multi-project

There are multiple Grails 2.3.11 projects I have that I would like to integrate. Is it possible to have a "multi-project" setup in Grails 2? For development I would think there could be a root project that (on the UI side) you could click a link to enter into another project. As far as production would go, when the war file gets deployed, all the projects under the root could get included somehow.

If this doesn't exist I could just copy all project files into one project and edit accordingly but the former idea seems more streamlined.

Comment: I use inline-plugins for applications like this.

Comment: Interesting. I assume that if each project has a different datasource then I will have to combine all the datasources into one `Datasource.groovy` and give unique names?

Comment: Plugins can't have a datasource config of their own, so the main application has all of that.

Comment: How would I configure which datasource goes to which plugin?